# How to reverse Grid column using React and Styled components

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components

id like to reverse these Components. I'm using standart display: grid; Google tells me its grid-auto-flow: dense; but it doesnt work. So i think maybe i have issue in components structure? Great way for me would be set every even would be reversed

In index.js

```
            <ContainerCard>
              <CardImg src={photo1}/>
              <CardInfo>
                <CardH2>Title #1</CardH2>
                <CardP>
                     Some text 
                </CardP>
              </CardInfo>
            </ContainerCard>
```

In Styled.js

```
export const ContainerCard = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }
  
`
```

[My localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67MMO.png)

Answer (score 0):

`flex-direction: row-reverse` would help you with your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

Comment: Ou sorry i see i have set display flex insted of grid. Grid is correct. I guess i cant use flex-direction when i have display grid?

Comment: Yeah, you are right, sorry. Maybe "direction: rtl" helps. Other than that you might find some solution suitable for you in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383511/achieving-flexbox-row-reverse-in-css-grid

Comment: rtl reverse everything even text.  :/